# load data from json into webview

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, json, webview

In my project i have a tableView with a lot of data from my json database. When i click on one cell i go into another ViewController where i will open a webView also with data from my json database. 
Everything works well but my webView doesn't open the link from my databse.

Here is my code for the webView.

Can somebody find any mistakes or can help me?

```
NSString* jsonString = @"http://heurigenapp.cache.gugler.at/json.php";
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:jsonString];
NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];
NSString* link = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Link"];
NSURLRequest* linkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
[webView loadRequest:linkUrl];
```

Comment: Your JSON is an array, it's not dictionary

Answer (score 2):

you are getting an array here instead on NSDictionary as there are multiple objects in response.

```
 NSArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];
```

so you need to choose the object then get the link
e.g

```
NSDictionary *dict = [jsonArray lastObject]; // im getting the last object from array
NSString* link = [dict objectForKey:@"Link"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this

```
NSString* jsonString = @"http://heurigenapp.cache.gugler.at/json.php";
NSData* jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:jsonString] ];
NSMutableArray* jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];

NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:0];

NSString* link = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"Link"];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:link]]];
```

Comment: into the (void)viewDidLoad?

Comment: no my app crashes, if you want to see my log you can see it here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5dhm3fix6kf2mvx/Q0UzfvkD8N

Comment: I can't see the whole console log

Comment: ok i have tested the code in a new project only with a webview. It works well :)!! But in my project with the TableView an so on it crashes :/